# how to use filter in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to implement filter using ElasticSearch I'm simply want to implement range filter I've the following data:

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
      "Id": "144039",
      "posted_dt": 1506951883637,
      "submit_dt": 1507609800000,
      "title": "Request for Information (RFI) # 306-18-0018",
      "fname": "RODRI",
      "email": "",
      "desc": "dummy Text"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get data from last 3 or 5 days I'm using this :

```
query = {
"bool": {
   "must": [
    {   
        "range" : {
            "posted_dt" : {
                "gte" : "now-3d/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
    } ]    
}
```

}

My mapping for posted_dt is :

```
"posted_dt": {
            "type": "long"
          },
```

I did try the filter as well but didn't succeed.

Please help.

Thanks

Randheer

Comment: Have you tried `"lt" :  "now"` ?

Comment: yes but didn't succeed

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping of `"posted_dt"` field is incorrect. You intend to store date which is in epoch in millis but you are storing it as long type. So the date range filter won't work on long datatype. Update your `"posted_dt"` field's mapping like :

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "posted_dt": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer [Date datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to share your mapping. Actually make sure that `posted_dt` and `submit_dt` are defined as `date` in your mapping. Here you are using a `long` which is incorrect to deal with dates.

A side note is that you should use `filter` instead of `must` in your case. Will be faster IMO.

Comment: thanks for your message here is my mapping for posted_dt

`"posted_dt": {
            "type": "long"
          },`

I did use filter as well but it didn't work :(